# Symfony, doctrine JoinTable condition

Tags: php, symfony, join, doctrine

I have encountered a problem with JoinTable attribute in doctrine.

```
#[JoinTable(
            name: 'table_name',
            joinColumns: [
                new JoinColumn(name: 'join_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'),
            ],
            inverseJoinColumns: [
                new InverseJoinColumn(name: 'join_A_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'),
                new InverseJoinColumn(name: 'join_B_id', referencedColumnName: 'id'),
            ],
        )]
```

This piece of code generates following sql:

`SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ON table1.join_A_id = self.id AND table1.join_B_id = self.id`

Is there any option / attribute / setting that will generate `OR` instead of `AND`, so it will be:

`SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ON table1.join_A_id = self.id OR table1.join_B_id = self.id`